# How can I insert a line between two matched patterns but before 2nd one

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to add "dns-nameservers x.x.x.x" line for specific ethX device to /etc/network/interfaces
(This can be changed, it maybe another line at another file.)

i.e. to add dns-nameservers to em1
i wanna use something like:

```
sed -i '/^auto em1/,/^auto/ .....' /etc/network/interfaces
```

currently:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

What I want:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-nameservers x.x.x.x (<- this line inserted)
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that will cover your current and future needs is to save each set of lines associated with a given device as a single record and then print it from a function, e.g.:

```
$ awk '/^auto/{prtDev()} {dev = dev $0 ORS} END{prtDev()}
    function prtDev() {printf "%s", dev; dev=""}' file
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

While that looks like it's just printing the input file as-is, look how easy it is to then just tweak the function to have it add a line at the end of the 2nd device:

```
$ awk '/^auto/{prtDev()} {dev = dev $0 ORS} END{prtDev()}
    function prtDev() {printf "%s", dev; if (cnt++ == 2) print "dns-nameservers x.x.x.x"; dev=""}' file
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-nameservers x.x.x.x
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

or only print the record for device "em1":

```
$ awk '/^auto/{prtDev()} {dev = dev $0 ORS} END{prtDev()}
    function prtDev() {if (dev ~ / em1 /) printf "%s", dev; dev=""}' file
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

or match on a specific gateways IP address or only a loopback or anything else you might want to select on or manipulate or specific line you want to print or anything else on a per-device basis.

Comment: Thank you very much, last example is what I wanted, I replace / em1 / with other devices and it still works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^auto em1/       {f=1} 
       /^auto eth1/ && f {print "NEW LINE GOES HERE"; f=0}1' file

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
NEW LINE GOES HERE
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

To clarify the comment with an example: matching will continue across files (and cycled if more than one pair of start/end pattern found).  For example

```
$ awk '/^3/     {f=1} 
       /^6/ && f{print "HERE"; f=0}1' <(seq 5) <(seq 4 7)

1
2
3
4
5
4
5
HERE
6
7
```

first input file doesn't have the end pattern (i.e. 6) but the search continues on the second file.

If this is not the indented behavior please clarify the question.

Comment: This would benefit from an `END` statement in case the wanted "auto block" would be in the end of the file (`END {if(f) print ... }`).

Comment: shouldn't matter, the insertion point is before the end pattern.

Comment: _This can be changed, it maybe another line at another file._

Comment: @James Brown please see the newly added example.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^auto em1/!b;:a;$bb;n;/^auto/!ba;:b;idns-nameservers x.x.x.x' file
```

On encountering `auto em1` print lines thereafter and insert required string before next line starting `auto`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this example works with em1 but not eth4, because I believe it's last device on my example and it's enrty doesnt end with auto (ends with EOF? instead). Thanks anyway, anything helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat program.awk
/^auto/ && f { print "THE LINE"; f=0 }  # auto and f flag up will trigger printing
/^auto em1/ { f=1 }                     # auto em1 raises f flag
1                                       # implicit print
END{ if(f==1) print "THE LINE" }        # if the "auto em1 block" is the last
```

Modified test data:

```
$ cat foo
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk foo
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.3.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.98
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
THE LINE
```

One-line version:

```
$ awk '/^auto/ && f { print "THE LINE"; f=0 } /^auto em1/ { f=1 } { print } END{ if(f==1) print "THE LINE" }' foo
```

Comment: @EdMorton I wanna say I did but but based on my command history I did it wrong. Sorry about that, it seems to work.